# Qt Creator can not load plugins after compilation

Tags: c++, qt

I compiled Qt Creator from source successful. When trying to start it a dialog shows up with a list of plugins that could not be loaded the message looks like this:

> Cannot load plugin because dependency failed to load: CppTools(3.1.83)
>   Reason: K:\compile-qtc\build\lib\qtcreator\plugins\CppToolsd.dll:
>   Cannot load library
>   K:/compile-qtc/build/lib/qtcreator/plugins/CppToolsd.dll: The
>   specified procedure could not be found.

The message looks the similar for all the plugins listed in the dialog. The library mentioned for each plugin is there. What could I be doing wrong?

Am on Windows 7 64bit using MinGW (GCC 4.8.2) that is bundled in Qt 5.3.1.

Comment: Are the DLLs on the Path?

Comment: @The_Anomaly: these are the dll that were also compiled from the same Qt Creator source. Do you mean they should be in the system path?

Comment: Ah, pardon me, I misread your original post.  My comment is not relevant.  

My experience installing Qt Creator on Windows has always been very positive using the binaries, but I assume that you have reasons why you need to compile it.  Sorry I can't help there--I hope others can.

Comment: This question is slightly off-topic here. A good option would be to ask in the QtCreator IRC channel: [`#qt-creator` at freenode](http://irc.lc/freenode/qt-creator/)

Comment: @leemes: I did that before posting it here. Am still in the qt-creator channel and no answer so far.

Comment: Okay. Another option would be the [QtProject's forum](http://qt-project.org/forums) but I guess IRC is the best place.

Comment: Did you build Qt Creator in debug mode?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: yes I did in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dependencywalker(http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on any of those dll's (CppToolsd.dll) and see what is that which is not allowing them to load. Also try adding Qt 5.3.1 (assuming you used this to compile QtCreator src) bin directory to your system path variable.

Comment: the bin directory of Qt 5.3.1 was already in the path that is why compilation succeeded in the first place.

Comment: Did you try running dependency walker on CppToolsd.dll, what did it show? It will show missing dll's (which this depends upon) as red.

Comment: Yes I did, most of the dependency I checked are within Qt installation directory. I was wandering whether there's a "make install" step that could pull all the dependency. I asked about the "make install" step in IRC (Qt Creator) and the answer was that there is no "make install" step, but then the build directory is polluted with many object files from build process. I will try to follow up on this with IRC and probably mailing list.